# How to Identify unique and duplicate records using sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has multiple values in a particular column, I am trying to write two sql query which will identify the entire set of duplicates and entire set of unique records, I wrote few queries but in the unique set I am getting one of the record from the duplicate set.

sample data,

```
pay_id, pay_ratio, pay_type, cor_id
123,    12,        C,        Annual
123,    12,        C,        Annual
456,    13,        A,        Semi-Annual
476,    43,        B,        Monthly
987,    32,        H,        Daily
987,    32,        H,        Daily
```

I am trying to separate the above data set as below.

Unique Data Set

```
pay_id, pay_ratio, pay_type, cor_id
456,    13,        A,        Semi-Annual
476,    43,        B,        Monthly
```

Duplicate Data set

```
pay_id, pay_ratio, pay_type, cor_id
123,    12,        C,        Annual
123,    12,        C,        Annual
987,    32,        H,        Daily
987,    32,        H,        Daily
```

can someone suggest me  how can I achieve this using sql query.

Regards,
Sai

Comment: If possible try to put your question in a format which is understandable. Thanks

Comment: show your work please, what didn't work about it?  Currently it seems like your just asking us to do your work for you, with no apparent effort on your side.

Comment: which column ? and what SQL have you tried?

Comment: I recommend baby steps.  Start by identifying duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using `COUNT() OVER()`:

```
SELECT pay_id, pay_ratio, pay_type, cor_id,
       CASE 
          WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY pay_id, pay_ratio, pay_type, cor_id) = 1 
             THEN 'unique'
          ELSE 'dupl'
       END AS type
FROM mytable
```

The above query returns `'unique'` for unique records and `'dupl'` for duplicates. You can wrap the query in a `CTE` or subquery and filter it as you like.

**Note:** The above query is based on the assumption that *all 4 fields* of the table determine a duplicate record. You may change the `PARTITION BY` clause as you like to address some other duplicate 'logic'.

Answer (score 0):

using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Unique:

```
;with cte as (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (partition by pay_id order by pay_type)
  from t
)
select *
from cte
where not exists (
  select 1
  from cte i
  where i.pay_id = cte.pay_id
    and i.rn > 1
  )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/LHIGTY81886

returns:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------+----+
| pay_id | pay_ratio | pay_type |   cor_id    | rn |
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------+----+
|    456 |        13 | A        | Semi-Annual |  1 |
|    476 |        43 | B        | Monthly     |  1 |
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------+----+
```

Duplicates:

```
;with cte as (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (partition by pay_id order by pay_type)
  from t
)
select *
from cte
where exists (
  select 1
  from cte i
  where i.pay_id = cte.pay_id
    and i.rn > 1
  )
```

returns:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+----+
| pay_id | pay_ratio | pay_type | cor_id | rn |
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+----+
|    123 |        12 | C        | Annual |  1 |
|    123 |        12 | C        | Annual |  2 |
|    987 |        32 | H        | Daily  |  1 |
|    987 |        32 | H        | Daily  |  2 |
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Group and count:

```
SELECT
  pay_id, pay_ratio, pay_type, cor_id,
  COUNT(*) AS [Duplicates]
FROM table
GROUP BY pay_id, pay_ratio, pay_type, cor_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 0 /* unique; > 0 - duplicates */
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC
```